# identify if any $http calls are currently executed

Tags: angularjs, ng-idle

I have an angularJS application that utilizes [ng-idle](http://hackedbychinese.github.io/ng-idle/) module in order to logout the user in case he is idle.
However I do not want to automatically logout in case there are any $http calls being made to the server. Does the $http service provide any means to check if there are any executing HTTP calls ?
I know I can add an interceptor to the $http service and keep track of requests and responds, however I'm interested if such a thing already exists.

Thanks

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361883/angular-js-detect-when-all-http-have-finished