# How do I know that all my $http GET requests are completed?

Tags: angularjs

Using AngularJs 1.6.5 I am making multiple $http GET calls using the for loop. Here is the code:-

```
for(var i=0; i < 11; i++){  
    var url = "/api/learner_qa/" + i;   
    $http.get(url).then(successCallback, errorCallback);    
    function successCallback(response){
        console.log(response);
    };
    function errorCallback(error){
        console.log(error);
    };
};
```

What I want to do is trigger a function when all the GET requests are completed.

I referred to answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23361883/angular-js-detect-when-all-http-have-finished/23362321/#answer-23362145) and want to know how can this be done on an array as in my case?

Comment: you can just increment a counter into the successCallback and when this counter is == 11 dispatch the new function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The time will likely arise where you need to resolve multiple promises
>   at once, this is easily achieved through `$q.all()` by passing in either
>   an Array or Object of promises which will call `.then()` once both are
>   resolved:

You can take an `array` and `push` your `http` calls into it

```
var array  = [];
for(var i=0; i < 11; i++){  
    var url = "/api/learner_qa/" + i;   
    array.push($http.get(url))
};

$q.all(array).then(function(response) {
     console.log(response)
}).catch(function(error){
    console.log(error)
});
```

**Using this `code`, the `response` will come once all your `requests` are successful.**

[**Here is an example documentation**](https://toddmotto.com/promises-angular-q#qall)